# How to store check box values (0 or 1) in Database

Tags: php

I would like to store check box values in data base in form of (0 or 1). If it's check then send value 1 other wise 0 . but it's always sending 1 in database filed.I tried but its not sending value.

select.php

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
<!--<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<html>
<head><title>Checkbox Demo</title></head>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="selectall.php" method="post">

<input type='button' name='Check_All' value='Check All' onClick='$(":checkbox").attr("checked",true);'>
<input type='button' name='Un_CheckAll' value='Un Check All' onClick='$(":checkbox").attr("checked",false);'>

<table align="center" style="width:100%">
<tr>

<th width="450"><strong>Form Name</strong></th>
<th width="150"><strong>select</strong></th>
<th width="150"><strong>Edit</strong> </th>
<th width="150"><strong>Delete</strong></th>
<th width="150"><strong>View</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:20%"><input name="a1" type="hidden" value="Authentication">Authentication</td>
<td  style="padding-left:8%"><input type="checkbox" id="" name="emailid[]" value="1" class="case"/> </td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:20%"><input name="a2" type="hidden" value="User">User</td>
<td  style="padding-left:8%"><input type="checkbox" id="" name="emailid[]" value="1" /></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:20%"><input name="a3" type="hidden" value="Change User_Password">Change User_Password</td>
<td  style="padding-left:8%"><input type="checkbox" id="" name="emailid[]" value="1" /></td>

<tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:20%"><input name="a4" type="hidden" value="Add Employee Details">Add Employee Details</td>
<td  style="padding-left:8%"><input type="checkbox" id="" name="emailid[]" value="1" /></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:20%"><input name="a5" type="hidden" value="All Employee">All Employee </td>
<td  style="padding-left:8%"><input type="checkbox" id="" name="emailid[]" value="1" /></td>
<td  style="padding-left:8%"><input type="checkbox" id="" name="emailid[]" value="1" /></td>
<td  style="padding-left:8%"> <input type="checkbox" id="" name="emailid[]" value="1"/></td>
<td  style="padding-left:8%"> <input type="checkbox" id="" name="emailid[]" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:20%"><input name="a6" type="hidden" value="Company Profile">Company Profile </td>
<td  style="padding-left:8%"><input type="checkbox" id="" name="emailid[]" value="1" /></td>
<td  style="padding-left:8%"><input type="checkbox" id="" name="emailid[]" value="1" /></td>
<td  style="padding-left:8%"> <input type="checkbox" id="" name="emailid[]" value="1"/></td>
<td  style="padding-left:8%"> <input type="checkbox" id="" name="emailid[]" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE" class="btn btn-info">
</form>

</html>
```

selectall.php

```
<?php
include('DB.class.php'); 
//create an instance of the DB class
$db = new DB();
$db->connect();
if(isset($_POST['emailid'])){


foreach($_POST['emailid'] as $selected){ 
echo $selected;

$data["as1"]=$selected;

$data["as2"]=$selected;

$data["as3"]=$selected;

$data["as4"]=$selected;

$data["as5"]=$selected;
$data["ae5"]=$selected;
$data["ad5"]=$selected;
$data["av5"]=$selected;

$data["as6"]=$selected;
$data["ae6"]=$selected;
$data["ad6"]=$selected;
$data["av6"]=$selected;
}
}
$db->Insert("selectdemot",$data);
?>
```

DB.class.php

```
<?php
//DB.class.php
/*****************************************************************************
/*Copyright (C) 2013 Narwade Jaywant 
For any details please feel free to contact me at info@technopia.in
/*****************************************************************************/
class DB {

protected $db_name = 'selectdemo';
protected $db_user = 'root';
protected $db_pass = '';
protected $db_host = 'localhost'; 
/*protected $db_name = 'infortte_yogesh';
protected $db_user = 'infortte_yogesh';
protected $db_pass = 'Yogesh@123';
protected $db_host = 'localhost';*/

//Constructor is called whenever a new object is created.  
function __construct() {  
$connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
mysql_select_db($this->db_name);

return true;
}  
public function connect(){
$connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
mysql_select_db($this->db_name);

return true;
}
//takes a mysql row set and returns an associative array, where the keys
//in the array are the column names in the row set. If singleRow is set to
//true, then it will return a single row instead of an array of rows.
public function processRowSet($rowSet, $singleRow=false)
{
$resultArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowSet))
{
array_push($resultArray, $row);
}

if($singleRow === true)
return $resultArray[0];

return $resultArray;
}

//Select rows from the database.
//returns a full row or rows from $table using $where as the where clause.
//return value is an associative array with column names as keys.
public function SelectTable($table, $where="",$fieldarray="",$debug="") {
if ($fieldarray=="")
{
$f_list = "*";
}
else
{ 
$f_list = $fieldarray ;
}
$sql = "SELECT $f_list FROM $table ";
if(  ! empty( $where ) )
$sql .= " WHERE  $where";

if($debug==1){echo $sql;exit();}
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if( ! $result )
return 0;
return $this->processRowSet($result);
}
public function SelectSingle($table, $where,$fieldarray="",$debug="") {
if ($fieldarray=="")
{
$f_list = "*";
}
else
{ 
$f_list = $fieldarray ;
}
$sql = "SELECT $f_list FROM $table ";
if(  ! empty( $where ) )
$sql .= " WHERE  $where";

if($debug==1){echo $sql;exit();}
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if( ! $result )
return 0;
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
return $this->processRowSet($result, true);
}
//Updates a current row in the database.
//takes an array of data, where the keys in the array are the column names
//and the values are the data that will be inserted into those columns.
//$table is the name of the table and $where is the sql where clause.
public function Update($table,$where,$data,$debug="") {

foreach ( $data as $column=>$value )
{
if($value !="now()"){
$fv[] = "$column = \""."$value"."\"";
}else{
$fv[]= "$column = "."$value"."";
}
}
$fv_list = trim(implode(", ", $fv));

$sql = "UPDATE $table SET "."$fv_list"." WHERE $where";
if($debug==1){echo $sql;exit();}
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
return true;
}

//Inserts a new row into the database.
//takes an array of data, where the keys in the array are the column names
//and the values are the data that will be inserted into those columns.
//$table is the name of the table.
public function Insert($table,$data,$debug="") {

$columns = "";
$values = "";
foreach( $data as $column=>$value )
{
$field[] = $column;
if($value !="now()")
$values[] = "'$value'";
else
$values[] = "$value";
}
$columns = trim( implode(", ", $field) );
$values = trim( implode(", ", $values) );

$sql = "insert into $table ($columns) values ($values)";
if($debug==1){echo $sql;exit();}
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

//return the ID of the user in the database.
return mysql_insert_id();

}
public function Delete($table, $condition)
{

$query = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE $condition";
$result = mysql_query( $query);
if( ! $result )
return 0;
return 1;
}

}
?>
```

Please include jquery.js

**Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `selectdemot` (
`sr_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `as1` enum('0','1','','') NOT NULL,
  `as2` enum('0','1','','') NOT NULL,
  `as3` enum('0','1','','') NOT NULL,
  `as4` enum('0','1','','') NOT NULL,
  `as5` enum('0','1','','') NOT NULL,
  `ae5` enum('0','1','','') NOT NULL,
  `ad5` enum('0','1','','') NOT NULL,
  `av5` enum('0','1','','') NOT NULL,
  `as6` enum('0','1','','') NOT NULL,
  `ae6` enum('0','1','','') NOT NULL,
  `ad6` enum('0','1','','') NOT NULL,
  `av6` enum('0','1','','') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `selectdemot` (`sr_no`, `as1`, `as2`, `as3`, `as4`, `as5`, `ae5`, `ad5`, `av5`, `as6`, `ae6`, `ad6`, `av6`) VALUES
(1, '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'),
(2, '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1');
```

Comment: Can I contact you at `info@technopia.in` to complain that you're using `mysql_` which is deprecated?

Comment: how could you help sir ..

Comment: I just showed you an answer below...take a look.

Comment: Replace that portion of your form and click submit. You will see what it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unchecked boxes will not send any data, so one way you can do it is to make hidden inputs with the same array values and name. It's kinda ugly, but it works. Here is and example (just one portion of your form):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="selectall.php" method="post">
    <!--selectall.php-->

    <input type='button' name='Check_All' value='Check All' onClick='$(":checkbox").attr("checked",true);'>
    <input type='button' name='Un_CheckAll' value='Un Check All' onClick='$(":checkbox").attr("checked",false);'>
    <table align="center" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th width="450"><strong>Form Name</strong></th>
            <th width="150"><strong>select</strong></th>
            <th width="150"><strong>Edit</strong> </th>
            <th width="150"><strong>Delete</strong></th>
            <th width="150"><strong>View</strong></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:20%"><input name="a1" type="hidden" value="Authentication">
                Authentication</td>
            <td  style="padding-left:8%">
                <input type="hidden" name="auth[1]" value="0" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="auth[1]" value="1" class="case"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:20%"><input name="a2" type="hidden" value="User">
                User</td>
            <td  style="padding-left:8%">
                <input type="hidden" name="user[1]" value="0" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="user[1]" value="1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:20%"><input name="a3" type="hidden" value="Change User_Password">
                Change User_Password</td>
            <td  style="padding-left:8%">
                <input type="hidden" name="passmod[1]" value="0" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="passmod[1]" value="1" />
            </td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:20%"><input name="a4" type="hidden" value="Add Employee Details">
                Add Employee Details</td>
            <td  style="padding-left:8%">
                <input type="hidden" name="employee[1]" value="0" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="employee[1]" value="1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:20%"><input name="a5" type="hidden" value="All Employee">
                All Employee </td>
            <td  style="padding-left:8%">
                <input type="hidden" name="emp_select[1]" value="0" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="emp_select[1]" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td  style="padding-left:8%">
                <input type="hidden" name="emp_edit[1]" value="0" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="emp_edit[1]" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td  style="padding-left:8%">
                <input type="hidden" name="emp_delete[1]" value="0" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="emp_delete[1]" value="1"/>
            </td>
            <td  style="padding-left:8%">
                <input type="hidden" name="emp_view[1]" value="0" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="emp_view[1]" value="1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:20%"><input name="a6" type="hidden" value="Company Profile">
                Company Profile </td>
            <td  style="padding-left:8%">
                <input type="hidden" name="profile_select[1]" value="0" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="profile_select[1]" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td  style="padding-left:8%">
                <input type="hidden" name="profile_edit[1]" value="0" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="profile_edit[1]" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td  style="padding-left:8%">
                <input type="hidden" name="profile_delete[1]" value="0" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="profile_delete[1]" value="1"/>
            </td>
            <td  style="padding-left:8%">
                <input type="hidden" name="profile_view[1]" value="0" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="profile_view[1]" value="1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE" class="btn btn-info">
</form>
```

This form will produce something like:

```
Array
(
    [a1] => Authentication
    [auth] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

    [a2] => User
    [user] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
        )

    [a3] => Change User_Password
    [passmod] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
        )

    [a4] => Add Employee Details
    [employee] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

    [a5] => All Employee
    [emp_select] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
        )

    [emp_edit] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
        )

    [emp_delete] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

    [emp_view] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
        )

    [a6] => Company Profile
    [profile_select] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

    [profile_edit] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

    [profile_delete] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
        )

    [profile_view] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

    [submit] => SAVE
)
```

Comment: This code is unable to store value into database in 0 or 1 format.

Comment: Your original post said you wanted to send both 1 and 0 and that 0 was not working. Put hidden inputs and it will send 0 values.

Comment: sir I want store values like if checkbox is checked then store 1 value and if unchecked then store 0.

Comment: Yes I understand that. Checkboxes that are not checked will not send any data. That is why you make hidden inputs with the same name so it will set the default to 0 and save it to the $_POST array. Did you see the results of putting hidden inputs?

Comment: sir, I try this but it's sending all value 0 to database

Comment: When you check off some of them, are those not sending a `1`?

Comment: sir please send edited code. because I am not getting your point clearly.

Comment: sir please help really its not working .. i tried much but not succeed.

Comment: See my update and what that form produces. Notice the `1` and `0` values in the categories.