# How to store values from check box generated from while loop into database?

Tags: php

How to store the value of mutiple checked checkbox generated by a loop.
I've already seen lot of ways to get values from checkboxes but what if it was generated this way :

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

         echo'<div class="checkbox ">
        <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" name="requirement_name[]" value="'.$row['requirement_id'].'">
        '.$row['requirement_name'].'
        </label>
        </div>';
    }
}
```

I was able to use this code but it only shows how many are checked and what is checked:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['requirement_name'])) {
        // Counting number of checked checkboxes.
        $checked_count = count($_POST['requirement_name']);
        echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['requirement_name'] as $selected) {
            echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";
        }

    }
    else{
        echo "<b>Please Select Atleast One Option.</b>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you want to do?  Store it? Store it where?

Comment: I want to store the value into another table @AbraCadaver. However I dont know how to do it if it's generated that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store check box values (0 or 1) in Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795185/how-to-store-check-box-values-0-or-1-in-database)

Comment: @Johan I have already looked into that but that one is way too deep tho.

Comment: The essence of the answer in that post is; use a hidden field that defaults the checkbox value to zero. Else the field is not posted along with the form.

Comment: @Johan I dont know if I could even relate my problem to that but I'm sorry I new to php so I dont really understand. And it's way too high level for me tho